# UITableViewCell width is greater than UITableView width

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I encountered a weird problem. I am creating a custom selected view for my tableviews. However, this selection view doesn't fit well. I found out that this is because my selection view is 300px while the cell itself is 320px. The weird part is that the `UITableView`'s width is actually just 300px only. How will I adjust the cell width of my table?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   static NSString *tableIdentifier = @"Cell";

   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:tableIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:tableIdentifier] autorelease];


  if (tableView == bandTable)
  {
    UIImageView *imageBg = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"column1_selected.png"]];
    [imageBg setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

    [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
    [cell setSelectedBackgroundView:imageBg];
    [imageBg release];

    NSArray *array = [bandDictionary objectForKey:@"Bands"];

    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"CELL: %f", cell.bounds.size.width);
  }
  return cell;
}
```

Comment: please paste your code CellForIndexPath:

Comment: If you're  not sure about width of your data, instead of trying to feet it using a `UIView` you can use `UIScrollView` and make sure to set its `contentSize` property as per your need. You'll need to scroll right or left to see the remaining (or hidden) data.

Comment: @Hemang It's not the data I'm concerned about. It is the custom selection view not fitting well. Like I've said, both the table and the custom selection view has a width of 300px, but the cell width is 320px.

Comment: Can't you explicitly set frame for imageBg as imageBg.frame = CGRectMake....

Comment: Can you check the table size programmatically ? I think `cellForRowAtIndexPath` will be a pretty good place for this check.

Comment: I checked it. The table width is 300.

Answer (score 4):

Just set

```
cell.frame = CGRectMake(0,
                        0,
                        self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                        cell.frame.size.height);
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: Thank youu. My cell was overflowing and this did it

Answer (score 2):

Add this two lines after your cell gets created,

```
[[cell contentView] setFrame:[cell bounds]];
[[cell contentView] setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

Answer (score 0):

@IvorPrebeg, you shouldn't set the frame for the `UITableViewCell` inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. The `UITableViewCell` will automatically be set to the width of the `UITableView` after the `cell` did execute `layoutSubviews`. This will be done automatically after setting a value on the label you inserted in the `cell`.

Its just important to calculate inside `heightForRowAtIndexPath` a size based on the font and the text inserted into the `cell` which is equal to the one inside your cell. In my case it looks like this:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
           heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{+
    ChatMessage *message = 
     [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    CGSize size = [message.text sizeWithFont:self.messageCell.labelMessage.font
                       constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(self.tableView.frame.size.width * 0.8f, HUGE_VAL)
                           lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

    return size.height;
}
```

**And than inside the `UITableViewCell`:**

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    if( _fInitWidth == 0 ){
        self.labelMessage.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 
           self.bounds.size.width * 0.8f;
    }    
    [self.contentView setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Like you can see, the `prefferedMaxLayoutWidth` of the `UILabel` inside my `UITableViewCell` will be 0.8 of the `cells` width (320 * 0.8). `LayoutSubviews` will be excecuted inside `cellForRowAtIndex` after setting up the cells properties. After that, `UITableView` will call the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` and calculate the size for the height. Therefore I calculate the `UILabels` size by passing a width * 0.8 for `constrainedToSize` ( tableview width is 320.0 * 0.8 ) the same as in the `cell`.

The example values are for iPhone devices, they will change on bigger screens of course.

Answer (score 0):

**On C#:**

```
public UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath){

  UITableViewCell cell = new UITableViewCell();
  cell.Frame = new CoreGraphics.CGRect(0, 0,this.selectSchoolTableview.Frame.Width, cell.Frame.Size.Height);
  cell.ContentView.AutosizesSubviews = true;
  return cell;
}
```

Another trick:

```
public UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath){

UITableViewCell cell = new UITableViewCell();
cell.Accessory = UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
cell.ContentView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth;
cell.ContentView.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight;
return cell;

 }
```